# How to click a button inside three div tags using robot framework

Tags: python, robotframework

i have 3 div's in a html script where 2 div's have ID and 1 has Class . and inside this three div's i have a button which i have to click . and i have to automate this click using robotframework

so am not able to click that button the code .so i tried with this two lines of code for clicking

```
Click Element  xpath://button[@id='Buttonmee']
```

and

```
Click Element  xpath://div[@id="container ABC "]/div[@class="row"]/div[@id="newdiv"]/button[@id="Buttonmee"]
```

So can anyone suggest me what to do ?

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the relevant part of the html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use from Click Button instead of Click element.
Click Button            id=Buttonmee